# Show that the given function is analytic in the entire plane minus the interval $[1, 2]$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem is for the complex analysis.

The problem is followed by this, show that ${[(z-1)(z-2)^2]}^{1/3}=e^{\frac{1}{3}f(z)}$ is analytic in the entire plane minus the interval $[1,2]$.

It seems that we just using the logarithm branch, but I'm novice in this part in grad student, so it is hard to figure out what to do.

Waiting for your help!

Comment: @Irreg Yet another irrelevant edit. Please stop them.